# Redirecting to a different controller view in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have to 2 models that are related ItQuery and ItQueryComment. When a user adds a ItQuery other users should be able to comment on it. What i am trying to achieve is when other users add comments on a query they should be redirect to the view of the query not the index page for the it_query_comments

here is my code for my comments add view

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('ItQueryComment'); ?>
<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo __('Add It Query Comment'); ?></legend>
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('it_query_id');
echo $this->Form->input('comment');
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

and here is my add function in the controller

```
public function add() {
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
$this->ItQueryComment->create();
if ($this->ItQueryComment->save($this->request->data)) {
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The it query comment has been saved'));
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'it_queries','action' => 'view', $itQuery['ItQuery']['id']));
} else {
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The it query comment could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}
}
$itQueries = $this->ItQueryComment->ItQuery->find('list');
$this->set(compact('itQueries'));
}
```

If anyone could show me how to do this, that would be awesome. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following

```
$this->redirect(array(
    'controller' => 'it_queries',
    'action' => 'view', 
    $this->request->data['ItQuery']['id'])
);
```

Comment: its still not pulling the id.

Comment: The 'id' of the Query to place the comment on should be somewhere in your posted data, if you followed CakePHP conventions, it should probably be here: `$this->request->data['ItQueryComment']['it_query_id']` Otherwise debug($this->request->data); before the 'save()' and check what values are present. You'll have to enable debug in your config.php to see this

Comment: @thaJeztah quick question how can i change this line in my add view echo $this->Form->input('it_query_id'); and give it a value of the id?

Comment: Because that field is the 'foreign key' to the ItQuery, you should add it as `$this->Form->input('ItQuery')`